# create google analytics code through API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Is there a google API to create google analytics code through API(not going to google site manually and create) ?

Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GA Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html) is read-only. You cannot create accounts or profiles through it:

> Google Analytics provides developer access to the configuration data through the Management API, which is a read-only API for account and configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

To load the script using the async method you can include the ga.js file in the head programatically. This can be done in different ways but this is a common way:

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);//<------ Set the account number!

// Add other values
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.example.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate',5]);

// The the script to the head
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
  ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +
  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

You can push values into the `_gaq` variable before or after the gs.js script is loaded. You can add many kinds of tracking for events, transactions and virtual pageviews at any point in the page. Nothing to do with usual script that get from the account. The only thing you need is the **account number**

Try Google's docs for more details:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html

Comment: thanks for the info but is that possible to create the  web property ID through API ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not create web property id through API.